# Model not found in Laravel 5.6

Tags: api, laravel-5.6

My route in `api.php` is like below

```
Route::apiResource('/suras', 'SuraController');
```

My Model `Sura.php`  is like below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sura extends Model
{

}
```

My Controller `SuraController.php` is like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Model\Sura;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SuraController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Sura::all();
    }
}
```

I am trying to browse in below URL

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/suras`

I am getting below error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for the class:

```
App\Model\Sura
```

But you declare your namespace as:

```
namespace App; // Which gives App\Sura
```

Therefore, just change the namespace of your class to:

```
namespace App\Model;
```

And move the class into `app/Model` directory.